# Reading AES1660 fingerprint sensor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sdk, sensors, fingerprint, biometrics

I have searched google for Fingerprint reader interfacing with MATLAB. But all the result I got is about fingerprint recognition. 
I actually looking for some way to integrate and read my fingerprint sensor which is built in my Laptop. According to driver it says its name as AES1660. It works pretty fine with its utility comes with driver of that sensor.

I there any stander way to use such fingerprint sensors in MATLAB? Should I needed some SDK? What if I dond find any SDK? 
I also tried to find out any documentation about that sensor that may help but in vain. The main idea is to reuse old laptops which have fingerprint sensors integrated with them.

I am not sure if such type of questions are valid for stackoverflow or not. But I am posting here because My question is to look some programmatic way to interface sensors with MATLAB. 
How to access such sensors in MATLAB? 
Thanks

Comment: Too broad as it stands, but try looking at this: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/

Comment: Really Really helpful, It increase my knowledge too much, I am reading this now, one more question do you think I can use this in MATLAB? as this library is written in C++?

Comment: There are ways of interfacing between MATLAB and other programming languages, e.g. `mex`: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/write-cc-mex-files.html  .  Sometimes it's easier to make a `system` call from MATLAB to another program which outputs data in an appropriate file format, then read the file in.  It very much depends what you want to do.